# writing a own application launcher for android

Tags: android

My Use case like this
- User is in my application 
- User presses home key (application goes to background)

Now user wants to go back to the same application (task in android terms)
one way is it through the application launcher BUT 
for my application there is no icon provided.

Instead user have to launch app with some "key combinations ". Essentially I have to write program to simulate application launcher.

So How can "application launching" be achieved with CODE? any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, how/why do you have an application that doesn't have a launcher icon?

Comment: Yeah Mayra , My application will not have launcher icon, infact it will not be shown, application will only by launched using key-combinations(say passcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start an application with an intent

I believe the android sdk samples have an example of a simple home screen application.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, writing a custom launcher is probably your best bet; check out this open source launcher for reference http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/